# @Inject adnotation a object dao give null

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I get a null pointer exception when trying to inject an object dao in service file.
Here is my code:

web.xml:

```
<context-param>
<param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
<param-value>classpath:/applicationContext.xml, classpath:/hibernateContext.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
```

applicationContext.xml:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.projects.discussion"/>
```

AccountController.java:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/users")
public class AccountController {
    @Autowired
    private AccountService accountService;

    public String postRegistrionForm(...) {
         accountService.registerAccount(...);
    }
```

AccountServiceImpl.java:

```
@Service("accountService")
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
public class AccountServiceImpl implements AccountService {

    @Inject
    private UserDAO userDao;

    @Transactional(readOnly = false)
    public boolean registerAccount(User user, Errors errors) {
        ...
        userDao.create(user);
        ...
```

When it comes to registerAccount method in AccountService, stops at userDao.create(). UserDao in the moment is NULL. Why?
I tried with @Autowired instead of @Inject, but it didn't help me :( 
Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

No, a processed bean with an `@Autowired` or `@Inject` target cannot have that target be injected with a `null` value. Spring will throw exceptions if it cannot find a candidate bean.

You must be creating the object yourself or it is created by some container other than Spring.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Problem solved. I forgot to add @Repository adnotation for userDao.

Comment: @Piotr You're welcome. Where we you creating a `AccountServiceImpl` object?